# dynamically intersect select queries on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have my access table in below format.

```
ID  access value
1   18      ab
1   32      bc
1   48      cd
2   18      ef
3   18      ab  
3   32      bc
```

I need to get all the id's who have access to certain numbers based on the input.

If the input is `[{access:18,value:ab},{access:32, value:bc}]`

```
select id from access where access = 18 and value ='ab'
intersect
select id from access where access = 32 and value = 'bc'
```

output is 1,3

If the input is `[{access:18,value:ab},{access:32, value:bc},{access:48,value:cd}]`

```
select id from access where access = 18 and value ='ab'
intersect
select id from access where access = 32 and value ='bc'
intersect
select id from access where access = 48 and value ='cd'
```

output is 1.

How to write the above query in a better way so that based on input I can achieve the desired result.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing the input as a json array. You may use `json_to_recordset` to convert it to rows and then do a join with `access` table and compare the counts with a `HAVING` to get intersection.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66b9c/34)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE access
    (ID int, access int, value varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO access
    (ID, access, value)
VALUES
    (1, 18, 'ab'),
    (1, 32, 'bc'),
    (1, 48, 'cd'),
    (2, 18, 'ef'),
    (3, 18, 'ab'),
    (3, 32, 'bc')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  ID
FROM access a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () as ct
    FROM json_to_recordset('[{"access":18,"value":"ab"},{"access":32, "value":"bc"}
                            ,{"access":48,"value":"cd"}
                            ]'
                          ) 
        AS j("access" INT, "value" TEXT)
    ) j ON (
        j.access = a.access
        AND j.value = a.value
        ) GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(ct)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66b9c/34/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine.  Another method is:

```
select id
from access
where access in (18, 32, 38)
group by id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I have added additional info, is it possible to loop the queries as the select is  of same parameters